# Spin box only works when up/down indicators are clicked, it does NOT works when it is edited by entering numbers

Tags: qt, qml

I have this Qt QML spinbox:

[image: spinbox]

The problem is, it actually changes value **only** when up/down (+/-) indicators are clicked. When edited by entering numbers into spinbox, it does NOT change value. I have tried many things, but I cannot figure out why. Can anybody help?

---

QML code of the spinbox is this:

```
StyledSpinBox {
    id: overhangAngleFactorSpinBox
    implicitWidth: 120
    implicitHeight: 30
    to: 1 * 100
    stepSize: 1
    from: 0
    Layout.leftMargin: 8
    contentItem: StyledTextInput {
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
    }

    value: 70
    property int decimals: 2
    property real realValue: value / 100.0

    validator: DoubleValidator {
        bottom: Math.min(overhangAngleFactorSpinBox.from, overhangAngleFactorSpinBox.to)
        top: Math.max(overhangAngleFactorSpinBox.from, overhangAngleFactorSpinBox.to)
    }
    textFromValue: function(value, locale) {
        return Number(value / 100.0).toLocaleString(locale, 'f', overhangAngleFactorSpinBox.decimals)
    }
    valueFromText: function(text, locale) {
        return Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) * 100.0
    }
    onValueChanged: {
        editorScene.overhangAngleFactor = value / 100.0
    }
}
```

---

`StyledSpinBox.qml` contains:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as QQC2

QQC2.SpinBox {
    id: control
    font.family: editorContent.labelFontFamily
    font.weight: editorContent.labelFontWeight
    font.pixelSize: editorContent.labelFontPixelSize

    background: Rectangle {
        border.color: editorContent.listHighlightColor
        color: editorContent.paneBackgroundColor
    }

    down.indicator: Rectangle {
        x: control.mirrored ? parent.width - width : 0
        height: parent.height
        implicitWidth: 40
        implicitHeight: 40
        border.color: editorContent.listHighlightColor
        color: editorContent.listHighlightColor
        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "images/spinbox_down.png"
        }
    }

    up.indicator: Rectangle {
        x: control.mirrored ? 0 : parent.width - width
        height: parent.height
        implicitWidth: 40
        implicitHeight: 40
        border.color: editorContent.listHighlightColor
        color: editorContent.listHighlightColor
        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "images/spinbox_up.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding `editable: true` to spin box. According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html#editable-prop), the default value for `editable` is **false**:

> editable : bool
>
> This property holds whether the spinbox is editable. The default value is **false**.